# How to pass a class as parameter to Web Api

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to pass a class as parameter to my Web API. Here is my code:

Web API:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public string Post(ClusteringObject _cluesteringObject)
    {

        return _cluesteringObject.NumberOfCluster.ToString();
    }


}
public class ClusteringObject
{
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfCluster { get; set; }

}
```

And my test console App code:

```
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57961/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var testData = new ClusteringObject()
        {
            Data = "asdf",
            NumberOfCluster = 1
        };

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/values", testData).Result;

        string res = "";
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            Task<string> result = content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            res = result.Result;
        }
    }
}

public class ClusteringObject
{
    public string Data { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfCluster { get; set; }

}
```

My post action returns 0. It seems, I couldn't pass my object to Web API thats why it shows default values of each properties. How can I pass instance of ClusteringObject to my Web API ?

Comment: First of all, your Web Api controller should inherit from ApiController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PostAsJsonAsync` will send `ClusteringObject` as `Body` in the request, I suggest you try 
`FromBody` like

```
public string Post([FromBody]ClusteringObject _cluesteringObject)
```